# c# StringExtension with Method Space

Tags: c#, string

I try to create a string extension with the method Space(int) in it. If I have an instance of a string, then its no problem. But without I have no Idea.

The call should be: `string.Space(2)` or `String.Space(2)`

**Not** `"".Space(2)`!!!

In this example, the method should return 2 space characters (`"  "`).

Anybody to help?

Comment: That's not possible. How about writing an extension method on `int` instead? Then you can write `2.Spaces()`, which I think is more readable.

Comment: @Sweeper: Sounds also nice. I'll take your solution. Thank you for the hint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An extension method is supposed to act on an object instance, that's how and why it has the syntax it got.

But in your case, your method does not act on a string instance, so what's the point of trying to define it as a string extension method? Just keep it an old boring static method. There's nothing wrong with ye'ole static methods...

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Sweeper:

```
namespace Exp.Util.Extension 
{
    public static class IntegerExtension 
    {
        public static string ToSpaces(this int aData) 
        {
            return new string(' ', aData);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For this concrete example I think you can simply work with the string constructor:

```
var spaces = new string(' ', 2);
```